# Troubleshooting 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'user'?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to use the `@login_required` decorator but I get a `'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'user'` AttributeError. I have the import statement `from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required` on the top but I still get the error. When I delete `@login_required` from in front of `def profile(request)` in my views.py the problem goes away but when I put it in there the problem is still there.

Middleware classes from setting.py

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    #~ 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    #~ 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    #~ 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    #~ 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
)
```

Comment: Can you post your MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES setting ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to enable 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware', because it sets request.user. You should also enable the other default middleware or you're going to have other problems.

Answer (score 3):

The OP's question may be answered, but I arrived here because I was experiencing this error on a Django project that already had AuthenticationMiddleware enabled, and had been running successfully for some time.

The problem turned out to be that I was accessing the server using a different URL, which was not configured in `ALLOWED_HOSTS`. This was throwing a SuspiciousOperation exception, and our Error 500 handler was trying to route this to a Django-CMS page.

Unfortunately, because the error happened so early in the request, not all the middleware had been processed, and `user` and `current_page` had not been added to the `request` object yet, so Django-CMS died from multiple wounds when trying to render the page, obscuring the real error in the process.

I had to use `runserver` and insert `pdb` breakpoints to debug this, because running under `mod_wsgi` makes it impossible to use an interactive debugger, and the backtrace wasn't useful.